# How can I freeze picture of camera with CameraX API in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm learning CameraX API, and [CameraXBasic](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic) is a office sample code.

*CameraFragment.kt* in *CameraXBasic* displays a real camera preview, I hope to add a *Switch* button to  freeze current preview, by which the picture will not change even if I move mobile phone camera lens.

How can I do with CameraX API? Thanks!

**CameraFragment.kt**

```
private lateinit var viewFinder: TextureView

private fun bindCameraUseCases() {
    // Get screen metrics used to setup camera for full screen resolution
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { viewFinder.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
    val screenAspectRatio = Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
    Log.d(TAG, "Screen metrics: ${metrics.widthPixels} x ${metrics.heightPixels}")

    // Set up the view finder use case to display camera preview
    val viewFinderConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        // We request aspect ratio but no resolution to let CameraX optimize our use cases
        setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
        // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
        // during the lifecycle of this use case
        setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
    }.build()

    // Use the auto-fit preview builder to automatically handle size and orientation changes
    preview = AutoFitPreviewBuilder.build(viewFinderConfig, viewFinder)

 ....

 CameraX.bindToLifecycle(
            viewLifecycleOwner, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer)
}
```

Comment: I havent try it yet but it seem `displayManager.unregisterDisplayListener` in `AutoFitPreviewBuilder.kt` might be one way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! but your code doesn't work.

Comment: What `unregisterDisplayListener` do then? Blacken the view?

Comment: `unregisterDisplayListener` do noting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `PreviewOutputUpdateListener` to the `Preview`, you can then decide wether to update the `TextureView`:

**Java:**

```java
preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
        previewOutput -> {
            if(!frozen){
               textureView.setSurfaceTexture(previewOutput.getSurfaceTexture());
            }
});
```

**Kotlin:**

```
preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener {
    previewOutput: Preview.PreviewOutput? ->
        if(!frozen)
        textureView.setSurfaceTexture(previewOutput.getSurfaceTexture());
}
```

[From `Preview` Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview):

> The preview use case **produces** a SurfaceTexture which streams the camera input. It also provides additional information for a View to crop, scale, or rotate for proper display.
>
> The image preview is streamed to this SurfaceTexture when the camera becomes active. The SurfaceTexture can be connected to a TextureView or a GLSurfaceView.

So `Preview` by itself does not render anything and just provides a `Texture` to be rendered, it is up to you to decide what to do with this `Texture` returned by
**`previewOutput.getSurfaceTexture()`**.

Comment: hi Zohaib!   tragically they have removed `setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener` from 07!  Do you know if a replacement?  Kindly, fattie